# Is there any way to get response when using standardSubmit: true in extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

We are using extjs 4.1.2 . When we try to use standardSubmit: true ,form gets submitted,but not getting a response like "success/falure" (like in ajax) based on which i have to show a popup showing save success or fail . Is there any way to achieve this ??

Comment: Please post your try code... I think we can able to achieve by using proxy for the underlying BasicForm's Ext.form.Basic.submit call.

Comment: was the below answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Standard submit uses regular form post and is expected to arrive at a different page, not receive data. If you want to do AJAX post don't use standard submit.